# Suscribing a method to "item-add" event from "Items" Collection With C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, outlook

I'm currently migrating a VSTO add in written in VB to C# for outlook.

The general idea, is to log every single email information into a database of my own.
I've searched thoroughly and it seems that NewMail / NewMailEX events(from the application object) are the best options to handle it.

However, both events won't trigger for emails received when outlook client is down.
I'm having problems while trying to process all mails that are downloaded on startup from the exchange server, so i thought that "Item-add" event from items collection, might address this issue.

I know for a fact that this can be addressed within "item-add" event because we are actually handling this issue in the VB code.

However, when a try suscribing to the "item-add" event for each Inbox folder in Outlook, nothing happens! 
There is no error nor exception thrown whatsoever.

in our VB code,
we could managed to suscribe to the mentioned event with this code:

```
outlookNameSpace = Me.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlookNameSpace.Stores(account).GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
Mailitem = inbox.Items

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) Handles Mailitem.ItemAdd
```

Here is my failing C# code:

```
//looping to fetch all my inboxes
public static void InitialOutlookConfiguration(Outlook.Application myOutlookInstance)
{
    Outlook.Accounts myAccounts = myOutlookInstance.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts;
    foreach(Outlook.Account myAccount in myAccounts)
    {
        Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = myAccount.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        string storeID = myAccount.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).StoreID;
        myInboxes.Add(inbox, storeID);

        foreach(Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox in myInboxes.Keys)
        {
            Outlook.Items myInboxItems = inbox.Items;
            myInboxItems.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(OnNewItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work when you subscribe to only a single account and a single inbox?

Comment: i did, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The object raising the events (myInboxItems) must be alive - otherwise it gets released by the Garbage Collector and no events are raised.
The usual pattern is to introduce  your own wrapper class that takes the COM object in question (Items) as a constructor parameter, stores it in a class member and sets up an event handler. You can then then create that wrapper class for each Inbox folder and store each wrapper in a list. That list must be declared on the class level to ensure it (and its items) stay alive when InitialOutlookConfiguration() completes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<Outlook.Items> myInboxMailItems = new List<Outlook.Items>();
    public Items InboxMails;


    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //watch.Start();
        //chequear el orden en que solicitamos la ejecucion de la configuracion
        //this.Application.Startup += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_StartupEventHandler(OnOutlookOutlookStartup);
        Outlook.Accounts myAccounts = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts;
        foreach (Outlook.Account myAccount in myAccounts)
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = myAccount.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            myInboxMailItems.Add(inbox.Items);

            foreach (Outlook.Items i in myInboxMailItems)
            {
                i.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(test);
            }
        }
    }


    public void test(object i)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Eureka!");
    }
```

Just in case anybody sticks with the same issue, thanks Dimitry for your garbage collector insight!